# Why doesn't this class work when in a separate file?

Tags: html, css

**ORIGIN:**

I'm building a new page where the first part, a `<video>` tag has to take the entire screen.

I usually create my own stylesheet.css file where I put all my style code.

I've notice that all my code in this file works, except this class, which only works if I put in the `<style>` part of my page.html.

The class in question:

```
.starsfalling {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: 100%; 
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

The html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video class="starsfalling" autoplay loop muted>
            <source src="media/fallstars.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't this class work in a separate file.
There is nothing which can interfere.

**EDIT 1:**

thanks to @Shelby115

I've noticed that chrome is overwriting this css class.
Why? I've put the !important aside elements of this class, but it does not still working.

**EDIT 2:**

I've read about this problem due to chrome 52 or up who manage the document flow in a different way, so to resolve this problem I've put my .starsfalling into a div with position relative.
now it works.

But I'd understand why.
Do you know a website which explain these thing fine?

Comment: Are you sure the other file is actually being referenced properly? You should include that part. "Not working" is pretty vague.

Comment: can you show us some html code where you care calling this class? are you loading your css file in your html file?

Comment: Right-click the element on the page -> Inspect element -> View the styles panel and see if: a) `.starsfalling` shows up but is crossed out. OR b) `.starsfalling` doesn't show up at all. If "A" then something is overriding it. If "B" then you probably aren't referencing the file properly or you need to refresh your cache via CTRL+F5.

Comment: Can you please share a minimal example? someway that we can see the error you're seeing

Comment: @Enrico724 Look for the style that's overriding it. It'll be the same method stated above, except you'll scroll through looking for classes that use `z-index`, `position`, etc. that aren't crossed out. That should help explain why. I suspect there won't be one and it's crossed out due to Kirtan Patel's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Elements like `<video>` and `<audio>`, doesn't support *class* attribute.

Check this to see supported attributes for `<video>` element:
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#the-video-element
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in the HTML code, after your file, another css file is loaded, containing the same class name but with different styles.

Answer (score 0):

Double check on the followings:

1. Check your link : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourcssfile.css">`
2. Check your classes names.
3. Check if there is !important on few
   css properties.
4. Check if there is others css from another source
   like cdn.